# Corsair m45 compatible with Ubuntu? (mouse)

Tags: dual-boot, mouse, compatibility

I'm building a custom pc, and I think of buying [this corsair m45 gaming mouse](http://www.corsair.com/en-us/raptor-m45-gaming-mouse).

However, in the requirements (at the bottom of the page), it mentions that I must have either Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows Vista, or Windows XP. I have windows 7 or 8 on my machine in dual-boot, do you think I could still use Ubuntu or should I look for another mouse?

Comment: Close Voters: This question is not asking for software recommendations; it is asking if this mouse will work or not.

Comment: which can only get opinions as answers - unless someone actually use that item.

Comment: I'm asking this question because when I ran over the specs of the mouse, it mentions that it was compatible with Windows: newbie I am with linux, I wanted to know if it would still work on linux. Now I have my answer, which is that it will probably work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it means is it will only be garunteeded to work with Windows. Having it as dual boot won't make any difference.

However...

I use a Microsoft Track Ball Explorer, made by Microsoft:

[image]

It works perfectly with Ubuntu - better than it does with my Windows 8 computer. Just because it doesn't garuntee that it will work, it probaby still will.

Comment: So, in anyway, I've got to take a chance?

Comment: I would suggest you do - I haven't encountered a mouse that doesn't work with ubuntu. Your choice tho.